# We will vigorously raise the level of politics

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "We will vigorously raise the level of politics" sound natural in English?  It is a translation by Microsoft Translator from Chinese (The original Chinese is fine).

> We will vigorously raise the level of politics.

Comment: Not very natural, no. I'm not sure you can raise something vigorously. You can pull a rope vigorously to raise a flag, but not raise one vigorously. It might be better as "We will work vigorously to raise the level of politics."

Comment: You can raise the level of debate.

Comment: I like  "We will work vigorously to raise the level of politics." It sounds very natural in both English and Chinese.                  Thank you.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Good idea! But vigorously? How's it done?